# (SFML library) RenderWindow constructor throws exception

Tags: c++, sfml

I am getting started with SFML with Visual Studio 2019. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEiZalvDOj4&list=PL6xSOsbVA1eaJnHo_O6uB4qU8LZWzzKdo) tuttorial and launched the app successfuly. But without any changes to the code I launched it one more time and it gives me this error:

`Exception thrown at 0x53582687 (sfml-system-2.dll) in Voidger.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000016E. occurred`

on this line:

`RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!"); //not really`

Ever since the app will output the same error and will occasionaly create a window if some magic stars allign. When I discovered the error I tried to create a new project but had issue with linker so abanded it as the other app didn't even start.

Here is the full code (provided on [official website](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "H\n";

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!"); // error line
    CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The funniest thing is that the code always launches, outputs the `h` in cmd and most of times exits with code -1073741819.

Edit:
[Here is config manager settings that I use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF71V.png)

Comment: It is possible that you are building the program incorrectly. Are you using 32-bit dll files and x86 VS configuration?

Comment: Where can I find this?

Comment: You download the appropriate dll files from the SFML download page. When adding the library to the project, check that the correct platform is selected (in the tutorial you have win-32). Then select x86 configurations in the tab bar.

Comment: @desus I have done just that i guess

Comment: @Dessus It didnt help unfortunatelly